# The best way for handle JWT SignatureException

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, http-status-codes

When client sends an invalid token to my server, the server will return 500 status code. I think that is ugly. Wouldn't 400 (bad request) code be more correct?
If 400 code is more correct then how to handle 500 error? I tried to catch `SignatureException` and throw ResponseStatusException but then I receive a response like this:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2020-10-17T09:34:26.939+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "400 BAD_REQUEST \"cause: token is invalid\"",
    "path": "/toucan/user/delete"
}
```

My specified message and status code are in message in error with code 500. Is there a way to throw 400 status without 500?

Comment: To explain why `throw ResponseStatusException` does return a 500, you should post the code you implemented.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's talk about the status code.
If the token sent is invalid, then the user is not authorized to use API which is `401` status code.
Then let's talk about how to intercept your exception in Spring. You should check the [official documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) and either use `@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, reason="Invalid Token")` on `SignatureException` class (or catch it and throw a custom `Exception` with the annotation).
Either implement a `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions through methods with the following annotation : `@ExceptionHandler(value = SignatureException.class)`.
*Both solutions are mentionned in the documentation.*